# Request with Post title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a post & request. 
I need when user on post page click on button "Add request" and filled out the form with his name and phone number, with this two params I had a post title or post ID on **requests#index** page

How I can do this?

---

http://rostbiz.herokuapp.com/posts/1  when user on this page click on blue button. He refer on form http://rostbiz.herokuapp.com/requests/new where he fill his name & phone nubmer. I need to know, that on page 
http://rostbiz.herokuapp.com/requests/1   I see this information:
1 name
2 phone number
3 post name (from http://rostbiz.herokuapp.com/posts/1)

I need hidden_field :post_id, but how I can recieve this ID on page http://rostbiz.herokuapp.com/requests/new

May be I can with request.referer get id for f.hidden_field :post_id, post_id
and validate post_id? But I don't know how do this:)

Comment: Please be more precise about what you want to achieve

Comment: What kinda of hidden info do you want to send? Sounds like this could be a case of nested models?

Comment: ideally I need send post id in my requests/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send post_id as a parameter

```
<%= link_to "new request", new_request_path(post_id: @post.id) %>
```

Find post in requests_controller's new action.

```
def new
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @request = Request.new
end
```

Use it like below in new request form

```
<%= f.hidden_field, :post_id, value: @post.id %>
```

Comment: I made it. Now I have Can't mass-assign protected attributes: post_id

Comment: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: post_id
Rails.root: /Users/savroff/rostbiz

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:46:in `new'
app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:46:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"vMu40LcJ2eCSijVeiM29uVnQy7C6qjnmbVKPze9LSr8=",
 "request"=>{"post_id"=>"1",
 "name"=>"123",
 "phone"=>"213"},
 "commit"=>"Create Request"}

Comment: oops... This code work))) I just add to migration and attr post_id